# DataTables warning: table id=[tablename] - Login failed for user 'username'

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm currently using the MVC framework /ASP.net. I've been using datatables on my webpage, but when I publish my webpage to our server, the datatable won't work alright and show this error. The datatable works just fine when I run it locally on my PC. What could be the problem?. The Stored procedure, BLL, DAL, DBML and entities I have seems to be working just fine too since its working before publishing to our server, I don't know where/what part of my code do I have to edit to fix this. Do I have to add something on my script to make it work?. :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblPackages').DataTable({
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        "scrollY": 380,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "AddPackages")',
            type: 'post',
            data: function (d) {                    
            },
            dataFilter: function (data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                return JSON.stringify(json);
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "Package" },
            { data: "CreatedBy" },
            { data: "DateCreated" },
            { data: "UpdatedBy" },
            { data: "DateUpdated" }
            ],
    });
});
```

Comment: There's some JavaScript here with some data in it, but nothing in here can generate that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the answer myself. Turns out its not really an error on the code of any of my scripts but rather the apps configuration itself.

To fix the Datatables Error when uploaded to the server. In the Web.config file under configuration>configsections>connection strings

change the connection string from

**connectionString ="Data Source=sample1;Initial Catalog=[databasename]; Integrated Security =True";**

to

**connectionString ="Data Source=sample1;Initial Catalog=[databasename]; User ID=[input username here]; Password=[input password here]";**

[image]

**Notes:**

1. How will I know and what connection string do I have to change to make it work? - In my case, I was using the Link to SQL Class as my DBML. So when I click my DBML which has this format, [DataContextName].designer.cs

under the function is a declaration somewhat like this
base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["**dbWebApplicationsConnectionString**1"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)

that bolded text is the one I have to change in the Web.Config file since this is the DBML/DataSource that I have that is showing me connection errors.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript you provided looks fine for me.
I have created a sample MVC application and Ran Jquery Datatables.

- **Home Controller**
  [image: HttpGet ActionMethod to get sample Data]
- **About.cshtml**

  [image: HTML Table]

@section scripts{

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '@Url.Action("GetDataTableGridData","Home")',//ActionName,ControllerName
                "type": "GET"
            },
            "columns": [
                    { "data": "CreatedBy", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "Package", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "UpdatedBy", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "DateUpdated", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "DateCreated", "autoWidth": true }

            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

}

- **Grid Output**[image: Output]

Hope it helps

Comment: I didn't marked it down.IDK who is.But its actually a good example for me to see how it is implemented in other way. However , it seems to be almost just of that same construct as mine. I do really wonder why it give me such error when published on the server. But when I run it locally, it works just fine. It then seems to me I have to change something in the ASP.Nets config, build configuration or something to be able to fix it. But I don't know where to go/edit it since I'm new to MVC and ASP.Net. :( :/